# A data texture to read all vertex coordinates in the shader. But my datatexture seems to be empty

Tags: three.js, shader

I created a BufferGeometry from an array.

[How do I adjust individual vertices in the vertexShader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76318881/how-do-i-adjust-individual-vertices-in-the-vertexshader)

It all works so far. Now I want to pass the vertex coordinates not only as an attribute but also as a data texture. The reason for this is that I need the vertex coordinates of neighboring points.
In line 195 I create a data texture but it seems to be empty. I still don't understand why. My goal is not to create the geometry with the vertices from the positions attribute, but from the same coordinates that are stored in the data texture. For this I create a data texture with the positions array. I also created an attribute vindex so that the shader can use it to read the coordinates of the respective vertex from the texture. Does anyone know why my data texture isn't working?

```
import * as THREE from "../resources/libs/three/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from '../resources/libs/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import WebGL from '../resources/libs/three/examples/jsm/WebGL.js';

const P = new THREE.Vector3();
const N1 = new THREE.Vector3();
const N2 = new THREE.Vector3();
const N3 = new THREE.Vector3();
const D1 = new THREE.Vector3();
const D2 = new THREE.Vector3();

const VS = `

    precision highp float;
    precision highp int;
    precision highp sampler2D;

    uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
    uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

    uniform sampler2D uSpatialTexture;
    uniform float uTextureSize;

    uniform float time;
    uniform int point;

    // Attributes
    in vec3 position;
    in vec3 normal;
    in int vindex;
    // Outputs
    out vec3 vNormal;

    void main() {   

        float wStep = 1. / uTextureSize;
        float hWStep = wStep * 0.5;
        float t = float(vindex) * wStep + hWStep;

        vec3 coordFromTex = texture(uSpatialTexture, vec2(t, 0.5)).rgb;
                

        //just initial normals
        vNormal = normalize(normal);    

        /*****************************************************************
            the goal is to get exactly the same result like with the normal way 
            but with reading the vertexcoordinates from the datatexture
        *****************************************************************/          
        //vec3 newPosition = coordFromTex + vNormal * 3.;
        //gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(coordFromTex, 1.0);

        //the normal way        
        vec3 newPosition = position + vNormal * 3.;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        
        if(vindex == point){
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
        }
        
}`;


const FS = `

    precision highp float;
    precision highp int;
    precision highp sampler2D;

    uniform sampler2D uSpatialTexture;
    uniform float uTextureSize;

    in vec3 vNormal;
    out vec4 out_FragColor;
    
    void main() {

        out_FragColor = vec4(vec3(1., 0., 0.), 1.);
}`;


class Main {
    constructor(){
        this.init();
        this.animate(); 
    }
            
    init(){
        
        if (!WebGL.isWebGL2Available()) {return false;}
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const context = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas,context: context,antialias: true});                    
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio ); 
        this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; 
        this.renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;  
        this.container = document.getElementById('container');
        this.renderer.setSize(this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight);
        this.container.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );
        this.aspect = this.container.clientWidth / this.container.clientHeight; 
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x557799 );
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, this.aspect, 0.1, 10000000 );
        this.camera.position.set( 30, 20, -30 );
        this.controls = new OrbitControls( this.camera, this.renderer.domElement );
        this.controls.screenSpacePanning = true;
        this.controls.minDistance = 5;
        this.controls.maxDistance = 40;
        this.controls.target.set( 0, 2, 0 );
        this.controls.update();
    
        //************************************************************************
    
        this.params = {
            resolution: 5,
            width: 20,
        }

        const positions = [];
        const vertexIndex = [];

        const resolution = this.params.resolution;
        const width = this.params.width;
        const half = width / 2;
  
        let idx = 0;
        
        for (let x = 0; x <= resolution; x++) {
            const xp = width * x / resolution;
            for (let z = 0; z <= resolution; z++) {
                const zp = width * z / resolution;
                // Compute position
                P.set(xp - half, 0, zp - half);

                positions.push(P.x, P.y, P.z);
                vertexIndex.push(idx);
                idx += 1;
            }
        }

        // Generate indices and normals
        const indices = this.GenerateIndices();
        const normals = this.GenerateNormals(positions, indices);

        const bytesInFloat32 = 4;
        const bytesInInt32 = 4;
        const positionsArray = new Float32Array(new ArrayBuffer(bytesInFloat32 * positions.length));
        const normalsArray = new Float32Array(new ArrayBuffer(bytesInFloat32 * normals.length));
        const indicesArray = new Uint32Array(new ArrayBuffer(bytesInInt32 * indices.length));
        const vIndicesArray = new Uint32Array(new ArrayBuffer(bytesInInt32 * vertexIndex.length));

        positionsArray.set(positions, 0);
        normalsArray.set(normals, 0);
        indicesArray.set(indices, 0);
        vIndicesArray.set(vertexIndex, 0);

        var uniform = {
            point: {value: null},
            uSpatialTexture: {value: null},
            uTextureSize: {value: null},
        }

        this.material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
            glslVersion: THREE.GLSL3,
            uniforms: uniform,
            vertexShader: VS,
            fragmentShader: FS,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            wireframe: true,
        });


        this.geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry(); 
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
        this.mesh.castShadow = false;
        this.mesh.receiveShadow = true;
        this.mesh.frustumCulled = false;
        this.mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);  
        this.mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI;
        this.geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(positionsArray, 3));
        this.geometry.setAttribute('normal', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(normalsArray, 3));
        this.geometry.setAttribute('index', new THREE.Int32BufferAttribute(indicesArray, 1));
        this.geometry.setAttribute('vindex', new THREE.Int32BufferAttribute(vIndicesArray, 1));
        this.geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indicesArray, 1));
        
        this.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
        this.geometry.attributes.normal.needsUpdate = true;
        this.geometry.attributes.index.needsUpdate = true;
        this.geometry.attributes.vindex.needsUpdate = true;

        //here i store all vertex coordinates in a data texture
        this.tex = new THREE.DataTexture(
            positionsArray,
            vIndicesArray.length + 1,   //width
            1, //height
            THREE.RGBFormat, 
            THREE.FloatType
        );

        this.mesh.material.uniforms.uSpatialTexture.value = this.tex;
        this.mesh.material.uniforms.uTextureSize.value = vIndicesArray.length + 1;
        this.mesh.material.uniformsNeedUpdate = true;



        this.scene.add( this.mesh );


        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.2 );
        this.scene.add( ambientLight );

        const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
        this.scene.add( this.camera );
        this.camera.add( pointLight );
    
    }//end init
    
    
    GenerateNormals(positions, indices) {
    const normals = new Array(positions.length).fill(0.0);
    for (let i = 0, n = indices.length; i < n; i+= 3) {
      const i1 = indices[i] * 3;
      const i2 = indices[i+1] * 3;
      const i3 = indices[i+2] * 3;

      N1.fromArray(positions, i1);
      N2.fromArray(positions, i2);
      N3.fromArray(positions, i3);

      D1.subVectors(N3, N2);
      D2.subVectors(N1, N2);
      D1.cross(D2);

      normals[i1] += D1.x;
      normals[i2] += D1.x;
      normals[i3] += D1.x;
      normals[i1+1] += D1.y;
      normals[i2+1] += D1.y;
      normals[i3+1] += D1.y;
      normals[i1+2] += D1.z;
      normals[i2+2] += D1.z;
      normals[i3+2] += D1.z;
    }
    return normals;
  }

  GenerateIndices() {
    const resolution = this.params.resolution;
    const indices = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < resolution; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < resolution; j++) {
        indices.push(
            i * (resolution + 1) + j,
            (i + 1) * (resolution + 1) + j + 1,
            i * (resolution + 1) + j + 1);
        indices.push(
            (i + 1) * (resolution + 1) + j,
            (i + 1) * (resolution + 1) + j + 1,
            i * (resolution + 1) + j);
      }
    }
    return indices;
  }
    
    
    animate(){
        //requestAnimationFrame( this.animate );  
        requestAnimationFrame( this.animate.bind(this) );  
        this.render();
    }//end animate
    
    
    render(){
        
        //this.controls.update();
        this.camera.updateMatrixWorld();
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); 
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera); 


        var index = document.getElementById("testfield1").value;
        if(index == '')this.mesh.material.uniforms.point.value = 100000000000;  //means no vertex selected
        else this.mesh.material.uniforms.point.value = index;
        
        this.mesh.material.uniformsNeedUpdate = true;

    }//end render
}//end class


new Main();
```

//------------------------Update----------------------------

Problem solved. The DataTexture wants RGBA. So I have to add an A channel even if I don't need it. Maybe I can use it for something at some point.

I uploaded a repository to github. Here the link:

https://github.com/Spiri0/BufferGeometry-from-DataTexture

But I have a new problem. If I set the resolution to 64, my geometry disappears.
I guess because the DataTexture isn't ready then. Does anyone know of an elegant solution that I can use to expand the repository so that it works with any resolution, e.g. even with 500? I don't have a need for such high resolutions at the moment, but it should generally work stably.

Comment: Right after you set the datatexture `this.tex = new THREE.DataTexture(...);`, try to put this line: `this.tex.needsUpdate = true;`

Comment: Right that was missing. But unfortunately no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution thanks to prisoner849 from the threejs forum. To refer to the fact that my problem is solved seems sensible to me, so that it doesn't remain an open question in the room forever. I also have a repository on github if anyone is interested.

Here the link

https://github.com/Spiri0/BufferGeometry-from-DataTexture